# FTP upload problem

Tags: c++, ftp, wininet, nas

I have made a program to upload to my NAS via FTP protocol.
My program runs fine when I try to upload to my web page, but when I enter the IP of my NAS, the following line returns false:

```
HINTERNET MyhFtpSession = InternetConnect(MyhInternet, "ftp://89.xxx.xxx.xxx/media", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, "MyUsername", "MyPassword", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);
```

What is the problem?
Is the IP line wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation for [`InternetConnect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Returns a valid handle to the session if the connection is successful, or `NULL` otherwise. To retrieve extended error information, call [`GetLastError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  An application can also use [`InternetGetLastResponseInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to determine why access to the service was denied.

In any case, the call is not returning `false`.  Assuming you meant it returns `NULL`, then you need to call [`GetLastError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and/or [`InternetGetLastResponseInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the information.  You can search for the meaning of the error code in the documentation on [system error codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  If you post the result here, then we might be able to help you fix your problem.

Comment: Hi. Looks like it works with this address: "ftp.89.xxx.xxx.xxx/media" worked. 
But thanks for the additional information for debugging my program in the future!

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you can actually connect to the site with FileZilla or something.

Also, what happens if you just put the IP address without the leading "ftp"//" and the trailing "/media" ???

Comment: Hi.
I can connect to the same IP from FileZilla. I even tried removing "ftp://" and "/media" in the IP, but still it didn't work in my program.